# A system with temp T is in contact with a reservoir of temp T. Would the system ever take in energy and expand (do work) in this situation?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, carnot-cycle

[image: This is the system in question]

The context is explain a Carnot cycle and how to get work from a system. Its starts by saying the system is in equilibrium with its surroundings, but then it take in some energy Qin.

How does this process come about? It surely can't happen spontaneously?

Answer (score 0):

It is being done reversibly, where the gas is only **slightly** lower in temperature than the reservoir.  It can therefore absorb heat from the reservoir very slowly, over a long period of time.  Since the gas is passing through virtually a continuous sequence of thermodynamic equilibrium states with virtually no temperature driving force, the process is reversible.

Comment: But the question implies there is **no** difference in temperature between the system and the reservoir. How does this process get started? Does there have to be a small amount of work done or a small amount of energy put into the system to start the flow of energy? If the temperatures are the same how does anything ever happen?

Comment: Good question.  Well, if it is an expansion, the external force that is pushing back on the gas can be lowered slightly by say, removing a tiny mass from the top of a piston at its initial elevation.  This will provide a slight driving force for the piston to rise, and for the gas temperature to drop slightly.  The rest of the tiny masses stacked on the piston experience work from the piston force and slight vertical displacement, while heat enters the gas from the reservoir until its temperature equilibrates.  Then, another tiny mass can be removed, but, at the new  slightly higher elevation.